# Get update db (in postgres) notifications in phoenix

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to now when a row changed in my db. I'm using phoenix 1.2.4. I already have the triggers using postgres, but actually I don't know if I need them.

Do you know how could I solve my problem?

NOTE: The data base isn't necessarily changed from the controllers, rather I have a cron that update some parts.

Comment: I have the triggers, but how those triggers can execute an elixir function?

Answer (score 2):

I saw this tutorial ([Publish/subscribe with PostgreSQL and Phoenix Framework](https://medium.com/@ruslanbredikhin/publish-subscribe-with-postgresql-and-phoenix-framework-ea80242745e4)) a few days ago and it seems like it contains exactly what you want.

It sets up the notification from the DB and then broadcast it. In your case, you just need the notification part and should be all good.

I hope that helps :)

Answer (score 2):

[Postgrex.Notifications](https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.Notifications.html#content) is the module which will use postgresql listen/notify to deliver messages to an elixir process.

A simple example:

```
defmodule MyListener do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(), do: GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [])

  def init(_arg) do
    {:ok, pid} = Postgrex.Notifications.start_link(MyRepo.config())
    Postgrex.Notifications.listen(pid, "my_table")
    {:ok, []}
  end

  def handle_info({:notification, _connection_pid, _ref, _channel, payload}, state) do
    # ... do something with payload ...
    {:noreply, state}
  end
end
```